# VS2015 - Disable Fuzzy IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

There is an option to disable fuzzy ("spellcheck-like") IntelliSense matching for member lists but not for everything else. It is ridiculous that I type "d3dev" and the first suggestion is D3D_CBF_FORCE_DWORD instead of ID3D11Device. If I try "id3dev" I get ID3DInclude for god knows what reason. C++ IntelliSense is just flat-out unusable for me and, as much as I hate to say it, MonoDevelop's autocompletion is leagues beyond what Microsoft has to offer.

In MonoDevelop, I can just type the first letter of each word (urd -> UnityRenderDevice, for example) and it pops right up. In VS, I type urd and it gives me UriBuilder_USE_ORIGINAL_FLAGS for pity's sake.

Please help me fix this thing. VS is my only option for C++ on Windows and I am so actively not wanting to even open the program anymore due to frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense should work in the way you described it, so there must be some sort error within your VS installation. Try a clean reinstall .